# How to compute geo distance between all pairs of objects in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, geolocation

I have setup one MongoDb (3.4) collection of N points with a 2DSphere index based on the 2D coordinates (ra, dec).
I want all the distances between all pairs of those objects
p1 = {ra1, dec1}
p2 = {ra2, dec2}
..
pn = {ran, decn}

=> d11 = 0, d12 = d(p1, p2), d13 = d(p1, p3), ... dnn = 0

How to construct the Mongo aggregation to obtain this?

Then I will sort this result, or select distances lower then some value in order to obtain the neighbours of each point.

Thanks for any hint

Comment: Can you start upvoting and checking answers that are correct so people are more inclined to help you? You have 4 questions you have asked and have never upvoted or marked an answer

Comment: I wanted to signal that my question has been answered independently from another post. How can I do this. Apparently I can nolonger "answer". Thanks for help. Christian